# Integer Time Intervals

Tags: java, math, time

This question is more of a math problem (Sorry, I'm not good in Math).

I have time represented as integer

for example

```
700 (means 7:00)

1330 (means 13:30)

2359 (means 23:59)
```

I have a starting time and ending time and want to create 15 minutes intervals between them. For example

```
int start = 700;
int end = 1300;
```

I want to loop over the starting time to increment 15 minutes and jump over 60 to next hundred. For example 700, 715, 730, 745, 800, 815, 830.. etc.

I can create this by creating a `Calendar` object and parse the integer as `SimpleDateFormat`, add the time to calendar, increase the minutes, and parse the hours and minutes back to integer. But its way too long to do it, there should be a simple mathematical way to perform this more efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **must** use integers, or are decided to, you can create a method "plusMinutes", like:

```
public int plusMinutes (int time, int minutes) {
    int auxMinutes = time % 60;
    auxMinutes += minutes;
    time += 100 * (seconds / 60);
    time = 100 * (time / 100); // set the last 2 digits to 0
    time += auxMinutes % 60;

    return time;
}
```

Another option (better in my opinion) is to create a method "toMinutes" and a method "toEncoded", like:

```
public int toMinutes (int encoded) {
    int minutes = encoded % 100;
    minutes += (encoded / 100) * 60;
    return minutes;
}

public int toEncoded (int minutes) {
    int encoded = minutes % 60;
    encoded += (minutes / 60) * 100;
    return encoded;
}
```

**NOTE:** Not 100% sure if the code works, haven't tested, but you should get the general idea.

EDIT: And for your problem when using the last option, you just have to do something like:

```
int encoded = 1330;
int plusMinutes = 45;

int minutes = toMinutes(encoded);
minutes += plusMinutes;

encoded = toEncoded(minutes);
```

Comment: Thanks, its the way I want it. Add minutes and convert back to encoded

Answer (score 4):

Use the [LocalTime](http://%09%20docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class. This has a plusMinutes method you can use to increment your base time by 15 minutes.

Maybe something like

```
LocalTime baseTime = LocalTime.of(((int)myNumber/100),myNumber%100);
while(...){
   LocalTime myTime=baseTime.plusMinutes(15);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert an "integer encoded" time to minutes:

```
int encoded = 2359;
int minutes = (encoded / 100) * 60 + encoded % 100;
```

Once you have minutes, you can add minutes, or milliseconds:

```
long milliseconds = minutes * 3_600_000L;
```

Answer (score 2):

The magic formula for this is **((j=i%100+15)%60)+((i/100 + j/60)*100)**

```
for(int i = 700, j; i <= 1300; i=((j=i%100+15)%60)+((i/100+j/60)*100)){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Output :**

```
700
715
730
745
800
815
...
1300
```

Comment: Impressive, a single formula! Great job

Answer (score 0):

There already have been quite some good answers.

From API perspective you should use the Date and Time API as user1717259 suggested, it provides best options for "calculating" with times. This'll produce the most self-explaining and maintainable code.

There also good suggestions for computing minutes and hours from the time-encoded int.

If using `int`s is a constraint and you just want to calculate the next int for a given start value and interval, the following function might help

```
int inc(int currentTime, int interval) {
    return (((currentTime +interval) / 100) + ((currentTime+interval) % 100 / 60)) * 100 + ((currentTime+interval) % 100 % 60);
}
```

The functions explained:

- `currentTime+interval` is your interval increase, it could also be replaced by a separate call of `currentTime += interval` before
- `(currentTime +interval) / 100)` will get you the hour
- `((currentTime+interval) % 100 / 60))` will get you `0` or `1` if you exceed an hour or not
- `* 100` will recompute the hour-value to a hh00 format
- `((currentTime+interval) % 100 % 60)` will compute the minutes overlapping the hour, `% 100` will get you the minutes, `% 60` will get you the minutes on top of the hour which will be added to the new hour value

You may test the function with

```
for(int i = 700; i <= 1300; i = inc(i, 15)){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

This solution does not work with intervals larger than 40 minutes (because of % 100 % 60) ... but maybe someone wants to fix that one :)